# Ledger Nano S undetected when Redeem Yoroi Reward - Brave

Tags: yoroi, ledger

I have a Yoroi account linked to a Ledger hw ( model s).

When I tried to redeem my rewards it asked to connect my ledger, which I did.
My ledger is on but Yoroi says that no device is detected...

I'm using the Brave browser so maybe I have to allow something.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that your Ledger working correctly via the Ledger app.

In Brave you may need to 'lower shields' ie disable the default security by clicking the lion icon next to the address bar, then disable security for the site/extension. Be careful here and double check your settings, just in case.

Double check Ledger connections via the Yoroi FAQ here: https://yoroi-wallet.com/#/faq/3

In Yoroi you can also check the log files for more information. Go to the menu Settings -> Support/Logs -> Download Logs